# Mandrill email not reaching mandrill activity box and not even the recipient(python)

Tags: python, email, mandrill

I m trying to send email using Mandrill Python

i m using the following code

```
mandrill_client = mandrill.Mandrill('myAPIKEY')
    message = {'attachments': [{'content': 'ZXhhbXBsZSBmaWxl',
                                'name': 'myfile.txt',
                                'type': 'text/plain'}],
               'from_email': 'myemail@gmail.com',
               'from_name': 'name',
               'global_merge_vars': [{'content': 'merge1 content', 'name': 'merge1'}],
               'google_analytics_campaign': 'myemail@gmail.com',
               'google_analytics_domains': ['gmail.com'],
               'headers': {'Reply-To': 'replyto@gmail.com'},
               'html': html_text,
               'merge': True,
               'merge_vars': [{'rcpt': 'reciveremail@gmail.com',
                               'vars': [{'content': 'merge2 content', 'name': 'merge2'}]}],
               'metadata': {'website': 'www.example.com'},
               'preserve_recipients': None,
               'recipient_metadata': [{'rcpt': 'reciveremail@gmail.com',
                                       'values': {'user_id': 123456}}],
               'to': [{'email': 'reciveremail@gmail.com',
                       'name': 'name',
                       'type': 'to'}],
               }
    result = mandrill_client.messages.send(message=message, async=False, ip_pool='Main Pool')
```

when i use this code, `Email Sent` is printed but when i check my outbound activity i see "NO RESULTS IN YOUR SEARCH CRITERIA"

If i am doing something wrong with my code, kindly correct me!

I tried looking for a tutorial by all i got good was API of mandrill-python.

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters,

There was no problem in code. It was perfectly fine.

One should keep in mind not to use any email ID such `smthin@gmail.com` bcz these kind of emails require SMTP setups, which i had not done(and still havent). One has to look for emails which is a private domain.